# Simple to understand algorithm for calculating betweenness centrality

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am looking for a simple to understand algorithm to calculate betweenness centrality. Input should be an adjacency or/and distance matrix.

The algorithm could be provided in all forms and implementations (e.g. pseudo code, python, ...). Running time or storage usage are not important so it could be a naive approach. Most important is understandability.

Comment: I guess you know how to calculate the shortest path (Floyd-Warshall algorithm for example) between any two vertices and therefore how to calculate the number of shortest paths. So, what is exactly your problem ?

Comment: @Damien: I know how to calculate the distance matrix to that effect (by n-times exponentiation of the adjacency matrix) but how do you get to betweenness centrality from there?

Comment: You have to modify the algorithm so that to keep trace of all the shortest path between two vertices

Comment: @Damien: How do you do that when you exponentiate the adjacency matrix?

Comment: I have not used this particular algorithm for a long time. Generally, in a given algorithm, if min(a->b) = min (a->c) + min(c->b), then you get a set of paths, by mixing (set product) all min paths from a to c and all min paths from c to b. a given path corresponds to an array

Comment: @Damien: I don't know but I think this is in a way done only implicitly when calculating the distance product. After doing this n times you arrive at the distance matrix but I don't think that the intermediate steps can help you with keeping track of all the possible paths.

Comment: I was not thinking of the exponentiation method especially. Wikipedia mentions the Floyd-Warshall algorithm for this